# Excel macro for renaming and sorting sheets in workbook?

Tags: excel

I have to rename near around 200 excel sheet in workbook and need to sort them also.
Anyone knows macro for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this for sorting

```
Sub SortWorkBook()
    Dim xResult As VbMsgBoxResult
   xResult = MsgBox("Sort Sheets in Ascending Order?" & Chr(10) & "Clicking No will sort in Descending Order", vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton1, xTitleId)
    For i = 1 To Application.Sheets.Count
    For j = 1 To Application.Sheets.Count - 1
        If xResult = vbYes Then
            If UCase$(Application.Sheets(j).Name) > UCase$(Application.Sheets(j + 1).Name) Then
                Sheets(j).Move after:=Sheets(j + 1)
            End If
            ElseIf xResult = vbNo Then
                If UCase$(Application.Sheets(j).Name) < UCase$(Application.Sheets(j + 1).Name) Then
                    Application.Sheets(j).Move after:=Application.Sheets(j + 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

for renaming

```
Sub RenamingSheets()
nmbr = InputBox("enter first number(enter only number) ", "Renaming Sheets")
For ws = 1 To Worksheets.Count
Sheets(ws).Name = "SheetName" & nmbr
nmbr = nmbr + 1
Next ws
End Sub
```